# How to add QLabel to QTableWidgetItem?

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidgetitem

I do this like that :

```
QLabel *qlab = new QLabel;
ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(3);
ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(1);
ui->tableWidget->setCellWidget(0, 0, qlab);
```

but nothing happen when i click on cell and i can't write text.

Comment: You need to insert a QTableWidgetItem in the cell and make sure it's editable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the item editable as follows:

```
QTableWidgetItem *tableWidgetItem = ui->tableWidget->item(0, 0);
tableWidgetItem->setFlags(tableWidgetItem->flags() | Qt::ItemIsEditable);
```